# Two toolbars in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

Is it possible to have two toolbars in CoordinatorLayout, one at the bottom one on the top and both are reacting on scrolling ?

Unfortunately this is not working:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/background"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `CoordinatorLayout` custom behavior, maybe similar [FooterBar](https://github.com/devunwired/coordinated-effort/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/coordinatedeffort/behaviors/FooterBarBehavior.java) from [coordinated-effort project](https://github.com/devunwired/coordinated-effort) as an example.

The [layout.xml](https://github.com/devunwired/coordinated-effort/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_footer.xml) is similar to what you suggested, but uses `AppBarLayout` once, and the `FooterBarLayout` on the bottom.